# Javascript in wordpress causes SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, chart.js

When using the following code in combination with chart.js, to create a custom legenda, it works fine in a HTML file. But when using it inside a wordpress page it is causing a Uncaught SyntaxError.

```
legendCallback: function(chart) {
            console.log(chart.data);
            var text = [];
            text.push('<ul>');
            for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
                text.push("<li>");
                text.push('<span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '">' + chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] + '</span>');
                if (chart.data.labels[i]) {
                    text.push(chart.data.labels[i]);
                }
                text.push('</li>');
            }
            text.push('</ul>');
            return text.join("");
        },
```

UPDATE:

Error screenshot:

[image]

Code error screen:

[image]

Comment: And how is it included in wordpress?

Comment: What is the exact syntax error? Is this code part of an object definition?

Comment: @epascarello it is part of the chart configuration in <script></script> tag

Comment: And where is the error pointing?

Comment: @MikeC Uncaught Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @epascarello to this part "text.push('<ul>');"

Comment: try replace this: text.push('<ul>'); for this: text.push('<' + 'ul>'); and check if are some changes (just for test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error screen shot, you have a line feed between `.text('` and `<ul>');`

This will indeed be a syntax error.

The line feed does not appear to be present in the code you've quoted in the question, but it is clearly there in your screenshot.

If you are sure that there isn't a line feed there, it is possible that it may be a stray invisible character that isn't showing up in your editor but is affecting the code when it runs. This kind of thing can crop up if you copy and paste code, eg from a website, where some of the hidden markup may inadvertently get copied as well.

Try deleting the characters around the error and re-typing them.

Comment: The code is not copied so there is no invisable character. When I remove the line, the SyntaxError jumps to the next text.push.

Somehow the wordpress page editor splits the code. Probably because it contains a html code? Is it possible to overrule this split?

Comment: hmm, that sounds like an odd thing to happen, even in an application as bad as WordPress. The first thing I'd suggest is that ideally your JavaScript code should be in a separate .js file; there are many good reasons for structuring your code this way so I'd suggest doing it anyway, but in this case it will also be an effective way of avoiding the current issue.  Beyond that, this is no longer a programming issue, but a WordPress issue. I don't have an answer for it, but you might get more joy asking a similar question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.